# Sticky Relative

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

Я бы хотел чтобы `top` автоматический вычислялось, здесь в примере я задал для `red` `top: 100px` но я хочу чтобы `sticky` был относительно положение элемента, типа `position: sticky-relative`, какие есть решение?

Или для этого **надо** использовать JS?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: relative;height: 300vh; ">
        <div style="position: sticky; top: 0; height: 100px; width: 100px; z-index: 1; background-color: aqua;"></div>
        <div style="position: sticky; top: 100px; height: 100px; width: 100px; z-index: 1; background-color: red;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Относительно какого элемента предполагается размещение красного квадрата?